# how to improve query performance to delete child table record faster

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

i have a table `Order` where i want to delete the data by `clientId`. This table have more than 2071458 records per client . And this table have foreign key reference with 16 table . Wo when i try to delete the record by clientid it takes 2-4 hours to delete the reocord . So how can i improve the performance to do it faster. May i use subquery if yes how can i use in this query . Below is the query that i am using .

```
DECLARE @ORDERID int   
DECLARE DEL_RelDataOFOrdeTab CURSOR FOR  
SELECT ORDERID FROM orde_ WHERE CLIENTID = @ClientID  
 OPEN DEL_RelDataOFOrdeTab  

  FETCH NEXT FROM DEL_RelDataOFOrdeTab  INTO @ORDERID  
   WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  

     BEGIN   
       DELETE FROM AUTHORIZED WHERE ORDERID = @ORDERID  
       DELETE FROM AUTODISPALERTS WHERE ORDERID = @ORDERID  
       DELETE FROM DRIVER_REIMBURSEMENT WHERE ORDERID = @ORDERID  
       DELETE FROM FAXPOD WHERE ORDERID = @ORDERID  
       DELETE FROM GENERICFIELDS WHERE ORDERID = @ORDERID  
       DELETE FROM [Messages] WHERE ORDERID = @ORDERID  
       DELETE FROM ORDAUDIT WHERE ORDERID = @ORDERID  
       DELETE FROM OrderNotification WHERE ORDERID = @ORDERID  
       DELETE FROM OrderNotificationActions WHERE ORDERID = @ORDERID  
       DELETE FROM ORDERSPAID WHERE ORDERID = @ORDERID  
       DELETE FROM ROUTESERVERORDERS WHERE ORDERID = @ORDERID  
       DELETE FROM UnfinalizedOrders WHERE ORDERID = @ORDERID  
       print 'DELETING FROM ORDE_'  
       DELETE FROM orde_ where ORDERID = @ORDERID  
       PRINT @ORDERID  
     FETCH NEXT FROM DEL_RelDataOFOrdeTab INTO @ORDERID  
     END  

CLOSE DEL_RelDataOFOrdeTab   
DEALLOCATE DEL_RelDataOFOrdeTab  

DELETE FROM orde_ WHERE CLIENTID = @ClientID
```

Comment: @PareshJ so what i need to use in this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the `CURSOR` and just use a `SUBQUERY`.

```
DELETE FROM AUTHORIZED WHERE ORDERID IN (SELECT ORDERID FROM orde_ WHERE CLIENTID = @ClientID)
DELETE FROM AUTODISPALERTS WHERE ORDERID IN (SELECT ORDERID FROM orde_ WHERE CLIENTID = @ClientID)
DELETE FROM DRIVER_REIMBURSEMENT WHERE ORDERID IN (SELECT ORDERID FROM orde_ WHERE CLIENTID = @ClientID)
DELETE FROM FAXPOD WHERE ORDERID IN (SELECT ORDERID FROM orde_ WHERE CLIENTID = @ClientID)
DELETE FROM GENERICFIELDS WHERE ORDERID IN (SELECT ORDERID FROM orde_ WHERE CLIENTID = @ClientID)
DELETE FROM [Messages] WHERE ORDERID IN (SELECT ORDERID FROM orde_ WHERE CLIENTID = @ClientID)
DELETE FROM ORDAUDIT WHERE ORDERID IN (SELECT ORDERID FROM orde_ WHERE CLIENTID = @ClientID)
DELETE FROM OrderNotification WHERE ORDERID IN (SELECT ORDERID FROM orde_ WHERE CLIENTID = @ClientID)
DELETE FROM OrderNotificationActions WHERE ORDERID IN (SELECT ORDERID FROM orde_ WHERE CLIENTID = @ClientID)
DELETE FROM ORDERSPAID WHERE ORDERID IN (SELECT ORDERID FROM orde_ WHERE CLIENTID = @ClientID)
DELETE FROM ROUTESERVERORDERS WHERE ORDERID IN (SELECT ORDERID FROM orde_ WHERE CLIENTID = @ClientID)
DELETE FROM UnfinalizedOrders WHERE ORDERID IN (SELECT ORDERID FROM orde_ WHERE CLIENTID = @ClientID)
DELETE FROM orde_ WHERE ORDERID IN (SELECT ORDERID FROM orde_ WHERE CLIENTID = @ClientID)
```

Basically, it replaces the `WHERE` clause from

```
WHERE ORDERID = @ORDERID
```

to

```
WHERE ORDERID IN (SELECT ORDERID FROM orde_ WHERE CLIENTID = @ClientID)
```

Comment: How can i change part two my storeprocedure

Comment: You can apply the same logic.

Comment: i try it but confuse in part two

Comment: It'll be the same. Just really look into it. =)

Comment: Thanks upvote from me today i understand how to use sub query . Many thanks